# How to iterate both through list and range in Common Lisp?

Tags: loops, common-lisp

For instance, to calculate polynomial in some point I'd have to loop through its coefficients `ai ∈ a0..an`, multiply each by argument power `i` and sum it all. (I am aware of Horner's method, just couldn't come up with better example) Of course I could of zip coefficients with some generated sequence and go through these pairs somehow like:

```
(loop for (ai, i) 
   in (apply #'list a (loop for i from 0 below (length a) collect i))
   sum (* ai (expt x i)))
```

But this seems cumbersome. Is there a way to combine it in a single loop?

EDIT: `mapcar`, not `apply`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First about your code. When working with lists you need to be aware of a few things.

- `APPLY` is wrong anyway, but don't use it with list operations. `APPLY` has only a limited number of arguments allowed - like any function in Common Lisp. Thus `APPLY` is not thought to do list operations or call list operations. It is used to call functions with a list as its arguments. If you use it with normal list processing tasks, any long enough list will trigger an error.
- calling `LENGTH` on a list should be avoided. To compute the length of a list, one has to traverse the list. For iteration purposes it is enough to map or iterate over the list. It will then terminate at the end. In many cases it is not necessary for iteration to know the length of a certain list.

If you want to loop two different ways, just write it down in `LOOP` as two variables.

```
(loop for ai in coefficients and i from 0
      sum (* ai (expt x i)))
```

Above loop terminates, since `ai` is only set to elements of the coefficients. `i` then just counts up. The `and` means that the variables step in *parallel*. You could replace `and` with `for` and then second variable could be computed based on the first variable. Similar to `LET`vs. `LET*`.